# Is it possible to create custom controls in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, custom-controls

Here is my requirement; I have a form where I get some account number from the user, for which I use a combination of text boxes, something like this:

Account No: [   ][   ][   ]-[   ][   ][    ][    ][   ][   ]-[   ]

*consider [   ] to be a textbox

Instead of getting the value from each textbox and combining them, is there a way I could create a custom control called 'accountNo' and display the textboxes as shown above and to retrieve the value using the control name 'accountNo'?

Comment: You mean you want to create a custom form components ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul yes, something like that so that i can avoid repetition of the same method again if it is to be used in multiple scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own component that extends a Panel or a FormPanel where you add all your TextFields in. Then you need to add a function to your custom component that return the concatenated value or all your fields. You can fine multiple examples on the web of component that's extends others.

Here's a place to start :

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext-method-extend

Comment: that helps. Thanks for your prompt response.